# When are variables defined in terraform?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

Terraform newbie here. I've a module with `variables.tf` which creates a resource 'folder' in Google Cloud. The variables are defined as:

```
variable "folder_name" {
    type = "string"
    description = "Name of the folder"
}
```

The calling function of this module is main.tf.

```
module "folder" {
    source = "../<path>/"
}
```

When I run 'terraform init', it throws the following error-

> ```
> $ terraform init
> Initializing modules...
> - module.folder
> - module.project
> ```
>
> Error: module "folder": missing required argument "folder_name"

I thought variables can be predetermined in a file or included in the command line options while running 'terraform apply'. I'd prefer CLI options, but then why am I seeing an argument error at the 'init' stage?

Answer (score 2):

You provide the value of each module variable when calling the module itself:

```
module "folder" {
    source = "../<path>/"
    folder_name = "xyz"  # add this line to define the folder_name variable
}
```

If you'd like to specify `folder_name` on the command line instead, you can create a variable in your `main.tf` file and provide that via command line instead:

```
variable "module_folder_name" {
  default = "xyz"
}

module "folder" {
   source = "../<path>/"
   folder_name = "${var.module_folder_name}"
}
```

And then provide this variable's value via the command line:

```
terraform apply -var="module_folder_name=abc"
```

Comment: That helped me understand. Thanks! Apparently, I had to create variables in the calling main.tf module and pass values from there to the folder module variables.

Comment: Yep -- you got it! :)